# Define char in header

Tags: c, variables, header

I have multiple C files 1.c 2.c and 3.c and their correspondent headers 1.h 2.h 3.h. these files use the same **static char*** variable so I want to define this variable in one header file. Is there any solution?

like : #define nameVariable valueVariable

NB :

- None of the c files include another header (i.e 1.c dont include 2.h and 3.h etc..).
- All of the 3 files include a 4.h file.
- All of the 3 files have the same Makefile.

Comment: Don't define variables in headers. There are always better alternatives. You can always use `extern`.

Comment: `#define` is for defining macros, not variables.

Comment: I can't use #define ?

Comment: declare it in one (or more) headers using `extern` keyword (without static), define it in only one cpp file (without `extern` and without `static`). Note: variable definition is like `int x`, and has nothing to do with `#define`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410632/2630032 for an explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the variable in question is a constant string that will never change, you can get away with using a `#define` for this.

In 4.h:

```
#define MY_STATIC_STRING "my_string"
```

This will perform a text substitution in each source file anyplace you use `MY_STATIC_STRING`.

Comment: What if I have a function that use this static string (i.e  functionX(static char* x);  ) that will be accepted ?

Comment: Yes, the `#define` is for a string constant, so you use it anywhere a `char *` is expected.

Answer (score 4):

Put this in 4.h, that all 3 include:

```
extern char* myGlobalVar;
```

This will **declare** the variable (just like declaring functions in header files), so the compiler does not complain when it sees `myGlobalVar` referenced in the other .c files (knowing that it has been declared).
Then put this in **one**(and only 1) of the 3 files (1.c 2.c or 3.c):

```
char* myGlobalVar = "blah";
```

This **defines** the variable, which assigns an actual value to it (just like when you define a function in the corresponding .c file). There can be multiple declarations of an identifier (such as myGlobalVar), but only one definition. So you could write `extern char* myGlobalVar;` in all of the .h files, but you can only write `char* myGlobalVar = "blah";` in one of the .c files.

Now you can access `myGlobalVar` in any of the 3 c files as long as they all include 4.h.

Comment: Should mention terminology here.  This is "declaring" the variable in the header files, and "defining" the variable in one of the 3 .c files.